# Perl File::Find is not working

Tags: perl

I want to search string in directory using Perl File::Find, but it's not working. It gave me an error:

> C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe D:/DUAN/MailScanner/GetMailForwarder.pl
>
> Error openning file: D:\DUAN\MailScanner\valiases Permission denied
>
> Process finished with exit code 13

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @dirs = 'D:\DUAN\MailScanner\valiases';

## main processing done here
my @found_files = ();
my $pattern = qr/World/;

find( \&wanted, @dirs );

sub wanted
{
    next if ($File::Find::name =~ m/^\./);

    open my $file, '<', $File::Find::name or die "Error openning file: $File::Find::name $!\n";

    while( defined(my $line = <$file>) )
    {
        if ($line =~ /$pattern/)
        {
            push @found_files, $_;
            last;
        }
    }

    close ($file);
}

foreach my $file(@found_files)
{
    print $file, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Code 13 is **Permission denied.**  `File::Find` seems to be working fine -- you don't have permission to access this directory or the files in it.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Is D:\DUAN\MailScanner\valiases a file or is it a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Very happy to see **use strict;** - good job!
The following minor code mod should help you get to the bottom of whatever problem you have.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @dirs = ('D:\DUAN\MailScanner\valiases', 'D:\DUAN\additionalPath');
foreach my $dir (@dirs)
{
    print "WARNING: $dir is not a directory/folder.\n" unless ( -d $dir );
}

## main processing done here
my @found_files = ();
my $pattern = qr/World/;

find( \&wanted, @dirs );

sub wanted
{
    next if ($File::Find::name =~ m/^\./);
    if (-r $File::Find::name)
    {
        open my $file, '<', $File::Find::name or die "Error reading file: $File::Find::name $!\n";

        while ( my $line = <$file> )
        {
            if ($line =~ m/$pattern/)
            {
                push @found_files, $_;
                last;
            }
        }

        close ($file);
    }
    else
    {
        print "WARNING: $File::Find::name is not readable. Skipping...\n";
    }
}

foreach my $file (@found_files)
{
    print "$file\n";
}
```